# Django - Update one fields value automatically after a value change

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and I have a simple question. I have two model: Model RegisterLogin and Model OtpEmailVerify. I wanna make 'is_verified' field of Model OtpEmailVerify 'True' as long as 'otp_no' provided matches with the 'otp' field of model LoginRegister.

**models.py**

```
class RegisterLogin(AbstractUser):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                             message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999-999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=False, unique=True)
sign_up_for_newspaper = models.BooleanField(default=False)
allow_remote_shopping_assistance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
otp = models.CharField(null=False, unique=False, max_length=5)

username = None
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'phone_number']

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    otp_choice = '1234567890'
    for i in range(5):
        self.otp += str(random.choice(otp_choice))
    super(RegisterLogin, self).save()

class OtpEmailVerify(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
otp_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='Please enter the Otp that has been sent for '
                                                  'verification ')
user = models.OneToOneField(RegisterLogin, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                  help_text='if it is true, that means can now validate otp for verification')

def __str__(self):
    return self.otp_no

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.otp_no == self.user.otp:
        return not self.is_verified
    else:
        return ValidationError('Wrong Otp Provided.')
```

**views.py**

```
class OtpVerifyView(generics.CreateAPIView):
queryset = OtpEmailVerify.objects.all()
serializer_class = OtpEmailVerifySerializer
```

**serializer.py**

```
class OtpEmailVerifySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = OtpEmailVerify
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_kwargs = {
        'id': {'read_only': True},
        'is_verified': {'read_only': True},
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need this code. django save and clean method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.otp_no == self.user.otp:
        self.is_verified = True
    super(OtpEmailVerify, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def clean(self):
    if self.otp_no != self.user.otp:
        raise ValidationError(
            {
                'error': 'Otp provided does not matched.'
            

}
        )
```